# How can I turn off syntax highlighting for man pages?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, manpages

I open man pages in vim, per

```
export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"
```

in my zshrc.

However, vim has syntax highlighting enabled when it opens a man page.  Is there a way to ensure man pages always have syntax off / that vim, when opening man pages, respects the vimrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an additional `syntax off` command to the `vim` command line in `$MANPAGER`, using the [`-c`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) option argument to pass Vim an Ex command to run during startup:

```
export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -c 'syntax off' -"
```